# How to add a Pandas DataFrame Output Parser to Langchain agent?

Tags: python, langchain

I am trying to add a PandasDataFrameOutputParser to an OpenAI tools agent - the objective is to get structured output. However, I am not being able to edit the prompt correctly and keep getting this error at the agent creation stage itself. What am I missing here?

In Google Colab:

```
%pip install openai langchain pypdf faiss-gpu tiktoken

#Defining a tool
@tool
def get_financial_info(co: str, fundamental: str, yr: str) -> float:
    """useful for getting information on a fundamental for a given company and year"""
 <code for returning relevant financial information>

#Defining a pandas output parser
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Year": ["FY22", "FY23"],
        "Sales": [0,0]
    }
)

parser = PandasDataFrameOutputParser(dataframe=df)
format_instructions = parser.get_format_instructions()
print(format_instructions)

tools = [get_financial_info]

#Prompt
msg = """
SYSTEM

You are a helpful assistant

PLACEHOLDER

chat_history
HUMAN

{input}

PLACEHOLDER
agent_scratchpad

{format instructions}

"""

prompt = PromptTemplate(
    template=msg,#\n{query}\n"
    input_variables=["input"],
    partial_variables={"format_instructions": parser.get_format_instructions()},
)

##openai_tools_agent
tools = [get_financial_info]
react_agent = create_openai_tools_agent(llm, tools=tools, prompt=prompt)
```

Error:

```
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-20-959030c40ed1> in <cell line: 4>()
          2 tools = [get_financial_info, change_yr]
          3 #prompt = hub.pull("hwchase17/openai-tools-agent")
    ----> 4 react_agent = create_openai_tools_agent(llm, tools=tools, prompt=prompt)
          5 
          6 
    
    /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/langchain/agents/openai_tools/base.py in create_openai_tools_agent(llm, tools, prompt)
         81     missing_vars = {"agent_scratchpad"}.difference(prompt.input_variables)
         82     if missing_vars:
    ---> 83         raise ValueError(f"Prompt missing required variables: {missing_vars}")
         84 
         85     llm_with_tools = llm.bind(tools=[convert_to_openai_tool(tool) for tool in tools])
    
    ValueError: Prompt missing required variables: {'agent_scratchpad'}
```